# CSS animations in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I have an animation that 'flies in' two boxes with a little delay and let them stay.

However, this code does not work in neither IE11 or Edge.

According to what I've read, both IE11 and Edge should support all animation syntax.

I hope someone can tell me why IE simply shows nothing (no animation, no boxes, nothing)

```css
@keyframes fade {
  
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
    
  0%  {transform: translateY(200%);}
  100% {transform: translateY(0%);}
  
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 769px)   {
  
#shopify-section-frontpage-boxes .usp > .grid{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(44, 140, 6, 0.84); 
   font-weight: bold;   
    opacity: 0;
   animation: fade 1s ease-out;
   animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-width usp">
 <div class="grid grid--no-gutters">
   <a class="grid__item" href="{{ section.settings.urlbox1 }}">
     <div>{{ section.settings.textbox1 }}</div>
   </a>
   <a class="grid__item" href="{{ section.settings.urlbox2 }}" {% if section.settings.statebox2 == false %} style="display: none;" {% endif %}>
     <div>{{ section.settings.textbox2 }}</div>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask], and provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: I ran it through validation and now it all validates. But it still does not work. I'm not sure what I miss in 'the right way to ask a question'. Can you clarify what my question is missing?

Comment: The Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ...

Comment: See caniuse.com about all the problems with IE and flex

Comment: Why do you have `from`, `to`, `0%` _and_ `100%` - this seems like a syntax problem for me. Combine all the statements into either `0%` and `100%` or `from` and `to`. So use `@keyframes { from { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(200%); } to { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%); } }`.

Comment: @somethinghere - excellent - thanks! That did the trick. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have `from`, `to`, `0%` and `100%` - this seems like a syntax problem to me. Combine all the statements into either `0%` and `100%` or `from` and `to` (as they mean the same thing essentially). So use

```
@keyframes { 
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(200%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%); 
  }
}
```